# Why are French nouns in -eur feminine when their latin origin in -or is masculine?

Tags: french, romance-languages

The [suffix -eur in modern French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-eur#French) typically gives feminine nouns: erreur, ferveur, torpeur, fureur. (Confusingly there's also -(a)teur which gives masculine nouns, but it seems etymologically separate).

The original suffix [in Latin is -or](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-or#Latin), with words like error, fervor, torpor, and furor all being masculine. In both Spanish (-or) and Italian (-ore), the suffix is also masculine.

Do we know when and through what process this suffix became feminine in French?

Comment: [_Development of gender classifications: Modeling the
historical change from Latin to French_ by Maria Polinsky & Ezra Van Everbroeck](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=D0B407AE168E4C62F8EF749CECB56F20?doi=10.1.1.134.9933&rep=rep1&type=pdf) section 4.2, pp. 376–377 (pp. 20–21 in the file) argues that Latin _soror, sorōrem_ (acc. sg.) and _uxor, uxōrem_ triggered that gender change. I'm not a specialist in Latin and the history of the Romance languages, so I'll just leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the answer, but the Spanish, Italian and Portuguese descendents of these Latin nouns are masculine, whereas the French, Provençal and Romanian equivalents are feminine. Some of the French ones (*ardeur, honneur, odeur*) went back to being masculine in the 16th century, but the only ones that are masculine today are *labeur* and *honneur*